# How can I get the physical size of a div, when defined as a percentage?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I'm looking for a way to collect the physical size of a `<div>` in pixels, when the `<div>`'s height and width properties are defined as percentages originally.

It is essential for the 's size to remain as a percentage, to I need to find a way to get the pixel size in either code behind (ASP.NET) or javascript.

Thanks in advance,

Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you do it with JavaScript.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/pvUC7/1/)

```
var div = document.getElementById('div-id');
alert(div.offsetWidth);
alert(div.offsetHeight);
```

When the page resizes, capture it by handling onresize.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/fdTqX/)

```
window.onresize = function () {
    var div = document.getElementById('div-id');
    alert(div.offsetWidth);
    alert(div.offsetHeight);
}
```

Comment: Quirksmode has the relevant [compatibility matrix](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html). It looks like `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` are supported by all major browsers!

Comment: Yea, this is the pure JavaScript method which has been supported for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of jQuery's 'resize' event and width()/height() methods, for example:

```
$('#yourElement').resize(function()
{
    var w = $(this).width();
    var h = $(this).height();

    // Do something with the data
    // ...
});
```